# Draw circle with ten or more control points in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am trying to understand how to achieve kind of circle with more than ten control points like in [this video](https://youtu.be/UrjDvPdXSyE), which can be adjusted to any shape and implemented in swift language.

I have [found](https://codepen.io/fuzzycat444/pen/dyXxKJQ) javascript similar effects, but I don’t know how to start. I also tried to use the Bezier path implementation, the code is as follows, but I don't know how to complete it.

```swift
class MyBezierPathView: UIView {
    
    private var path: UIBezierPath?
    
    // start point
    var startP = CGPoint.zero
    
    // end point
    var endP = CGPoint.zero
    
    // control point
    var controlP = CGPoint.zero
    
    var pathColor: UIColor?
     
    var pathWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    // current touch point
    private var currentTouchP = 0
    
    // init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    // draw BezierPath
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        path = UIBezierPath()
        path?.move(to: startP)

        path?.addQuadCurve(to: endP, controlPoint: controlP)

        path?.lineWidth = pathWidth
        pathColor?.setStroke()
        path?.stroke()

        path = UIBezierPath()

        path?.lineWidth = 1
        UIColor.gray.setStroke()
        
        let lengths: [CGFloat] = [5]
        path?.setLineDash(lengths, count: 1, phase: 1)
        path?.move(to: controlP)
        path?.addLine(to: startP)
        path?.stroke()

        path?.move(to: controlP)
        path?.addLine(to: endP)
        path?.stroke()
    
        
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: startP, radius: 4, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        path?.fill()
        
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: endP, radius: 4, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        path?.fill()
        
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: controlP, radius: 3, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        path?.lineWidth = 2
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        path?.stroke()
        
        let startMsgRect = CGRect(x: startP.x + 8, y: startP.y - 7, width: 50, height: 20)
        "start point".draw(in: startMsgRect, withAttributes: nil)

        let endMsgRect = CGRect(x: endP.x + 8, y: endP.y - 7, width: 50, height: 20)
        "end point".draw(in: endMsgRect, withAttributes: nil)

        let control1MsgRect = CGRect(x: controlP.x + 8, y: controlP.y - 7, width: 50, height: 20)
        "control point".draw(in: control1MsgRect, withAttributes: nil)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        let startPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self)     
        
        let startR = CGRect(x: startP.x - 4, y: startP.y - 4, width: 80, height: 80)
        let endR = CGRect(x: endP.x - 4, y: endP.y - 4, width: 80, height: 80)
        let controlR = CGRect(x: controlP.x - 4, y: controlP.y - 4, width: 80, height: 80)
        
        guard let startPoint = startPoint else {
            print("startPoint is nil.")
            return
        }
        
        if startR.contains(startPoint) {
            currentTouchP = 1
        } else if endR.contains(startPoint) {
            currentTouchP = 2
        } else if controlR.contains(startPoint) {
            currentTouchP = 3
        }
    }
    

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       
        var touchPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self)
        
        
        if touchPoint!.x < 0 {
           touchPoint!.x = 0
        }

        if touchPoint!.x > bounds.size.width {
            touchPoint!.x = bounds.size.width
        }
        if touchPoint!.y < 0 {
            touchPoint!.y = 0
        }

        if touchPoint!.y > bounds.size.height {
            touchPoint!.y = bounds.size.height
        }
        
        switch currentTouchP {
        case 1:
            startP = touchPoint!
        case 2:
            endP = touchPoint!
        case 3:
            controlP = touchPoint!
        default:
            break
        }
               
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        currentTouchP = 0
    }
    
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
}
```

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height)

        let pathView = MyBezierPathView(frame: frame)
        
        pathView.startP = CGPoint(x: 110, y: 150)
        pathView.endP = CGPoint(x: 258.47, y: 211.53)
        pathView.controlP = CGPoint(x: 196.94, y: 150)
        pathView.pathColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.1491314173, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        pathView.pathWidth = 2

        pathView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        pathView.layer.borderWidth = 1

        view.addSubview(pathView)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could approach this problem

- create a circle from several curve segments (using `addQuadCurve()` or `addCurve()` of `UIBezierPath` class)
- `addQuadCurve()` adds a curve with one `control point` while `addCurve()` adds a curve with 2 `control points` (the video you showed seems using paths with 2 `control points`, so it would be better using `addCurve()`)
- Then user needs to be able to move any of `start/end` and `control points` of these curves.
- For each these change, you have to redraw the curves

I have created a sample playground with this idea. In this playground, I have created a red circle (not a perfect circle) by four curves using `addQuadCurve()`. This circle has 8 points you could use to alter the shape. If you use 4 curves with `addCurve()`, then you will have 12 points to alter the shape.

Then I changed a single point of the red circle and added the updated shape in green color below the original red circle.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 700))

let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 500, height: 350))

let layer1 = CAShapeLayer()
layer1.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
layer1.lineWidth = 5
layer1.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

//create a circle wich has 8 points to change it's shape (4 control points and 4 start/end points of curves)
let originalPath = UIBezierPath()
originalPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
originalPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 190, y: 10))
originalPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 190, y: 190))
originalPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 190))
originalPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))

//add this path to the layer1
layer1.path = originalPath.cgPath


//suppose user move the CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100) to CGPoint(x: 220, y: 100)
//then we can redraw the 4 curves again

let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 350, width: 500, height: 350))

let layer2 = CAShapeLayer()
layer2.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
layer2.lineWidth = 5
layer2.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

//changedPath is almost same as originalPath except CGPoint(x: 250, y: 100)
let changedPath = UIBezierPath()
changedPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
changedPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 100), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 190, y: 10)) // <---- user has moved point CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100) to CGPoint(x: 250, y: 100). So add this curve to the new point
changedPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 190, y: 190))
changedPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 190))
changedPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))

//adding changed path to layer2
layer2.path = changedPath.cgPath

view1.layer.addSublayer(layer1)
view2.layer.addSublayer(layer2)

container.addSubview(view1)
container.addSubview(view2)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container
```